# Adding an x in front of and after words in a list

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

It's basic as far as Python goes, but I need to create a function  List of words as an input parameter and outputs them as a single String formatted as a sentence with a period at the end and lower case 'x's around each word.

e.g.
Input: `["This", "is", "a", "sentence"]`

Returns: `"xThisx xisx xax xsentencex.`

I think I need a for loop, but I keep getting errors in trying them.

Thanks in advance!

The closest I've come is through:

```
quote = ["This","is","a","sentence"]

def problem3(quote):
    blue='x x '.join(quote)
    return(blue)
```

which returns `"Thisx x isx x ax x sentence"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
quote = ["This","is","a","sentence"]

s = ""
for word in quote:
    s = s + "x" + word + "x "
s = s[:-1]
print(s)


Out[17]: 'xThisx xisx xax xsentencex'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list_ = ["This", "is", "a", "sentence"]

string =''

for item in list_:
    string += ' x' +item+'x'
string = string.strip()
print(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Map the initial list

```
>>> list_ = ["This", "is", "a", "sentence"]
>>> newlist = list(map(lambda word: f"x{word}x", list_))
>>> print(newlist)
['xThisx', 'xisx', 'xax', 'xsentencex']
```

And then reduce it to get the complete sentence

```
>>> import functools
>>> result = functools.reduce(lambda a,b : f"{a} {b}", newlist2)
>>> print(result)
xThisx xisx xax xsentencex
```